# Why isn't the CSS line-height the same when long text wraps?

Tags: css

With the following HTML and CSS, why is there space the 1st paragraph, but not the 2nd or 3rd? The line-height is the same for all of them. How do I fix it so there is the same space about all 3 of the paragraphs?

I'm seeing this on Chrome, not sure if others see it or not.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA &amp; AAAAA</span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em">BBBBB · BBBBB · BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCCCCC &amp; CCCCCCCCCC</span></span></p>
  <p>This is a paragraph without any spans, it needs to look correct too.</p>
</div>
```

Image of the issue in case this is browser-specific:

[image]

*edit:* Added another `p` without any `span`s. This needs to look correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, you can remove your **font-size:0.5em** from the span's style attribute in your html, and into the styling of **.wrapper p** in your css.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA &amp; AAAAA</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span>BBBBB · BBBBB · BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCCCCC &amp; CCCCCCCCCC</span></p>
</div>
<!-- Also removed the extra spans in the first and third p's, as they would now serve no purpose. -->
```

```
.wrapper p {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size:0.5em; /* This is added */
}
```

[image: Result]

This addresses the **relationship between** your **font-size in your span** and the **parent element's font-size**.

The **em is relative to the *parent* element's font-size**. The parent of the **span** is the **p** element, which inherits the font-size of the **.wrapper**, which is **20pt**. Therefore, your span's minimum-height is set to **10pt**, while your p's minimum height is **20pt**.

So the gap exists because your span is half the size (0.5em) of your p, and when the text wraps in your span, it fills in the remaining space in the p, which is why the other two had no gaps.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Scroll to the end to get the fix if you want to avoid the <strike>boring and long</strike> explanation*</sup>

You need to consider 3 things. First, `line-height` applied to block element define the minimum height of the line box.

> On a **block container elemen**t whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the **minimal height of line boxes** within the element <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)</sup>

In your case the minimum height is equal to `22pt = 1.2*20pt`. Even if the `p` element is empty you will at least have this height:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span></span></p>
</div>
```

Second, you should note that an `inline-block` element is placed in one line box even if the text wrap inside it. We may have more than one line boxes inside it but it doesn't matter because your span elements will then take one line box from `p`

> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements) are called **atomic inline-level boxes** because they participate in their inline formatting context as **a single opaque box.** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)</sup>

The last thing you need to consider is vertical alignment which is by default baseline and define how our elements are placed inside the line box.

---

Now we have everything to understand what is happening:

In the first case, you have a span with one line of text and a `font-size` equal to `0.5em` so the height will be around half the height of the line box of its container `p`. That element will be aligned at the baseline of the `p` element. Basically, we have an element having its height less than the line box so there is some free space to align it.

For the other cases, you have an element with 2 lines inside it, the same `font-size` but a height almost equal to the height of the line box where they are. If you look closely you will notice that the height of the `p` is even bigger because the baseline alignment will leave some space at the bottom.

So for the first case, we put a small element in a big space aligned at the baseline and for the other cases, an element in a space that fit it, also at the baseline.

Here is a better illustration to see what is happening. Notice how all the 3 elements are aligned the same at the bottom (the basline) and how the last 2 elements are slightly bigger.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  width: 175px;
  margin:0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
}

.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA &amp; AAAAA</span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em">BBBBB · BBBBB · BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCCCCC &amp; CCCCCCCCCC</span></span></p>
</div>
```

Here is another illustration to see the effect of vertical alignment:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  width: 70px;
  margin:0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA </span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:top"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA </span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:bottom"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA </span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:top">BBBBB  BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:bottom">BBBBB  BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em">BBBBB  BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCC CCCCC</span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:bottom"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCC CCCCC</span></span></p>
</div>
```

Notice how `vertical-align` different from baseline will have no effect on the element in the second case since the element is bigger that the minimum height defined so its height will define the height of the line box and there is no free space to align it unlike in the first case.

---

If you remove `inline-block` from the span element, you will remove the second part I have explained and each line inside the same will be placed in a different linebox inside the `p`.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  width: 70px;
  margin:0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

.wrapper p span {
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA </span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:top"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA </span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:bottom"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA </span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:top">BBBBB  BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:bottom">BBBBB  BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em">BBBBB  BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCC CCCCC</span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em;vertical-align:bottom"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCC CCCCC</span></span></p>
</div>
```

If we consider the second case, we had an `inline-block` element with 3 line boxes inside it placed inside one line box of the `p` element. Now, we have an inline element placed inside 3 line boxes of the `p` elements.

---

To avoid this, simply make sure that the `line-height` is equal to only one line of text. Eiher use a small `line-height` (even 0 will do the job) and make sure to redefine it for `span` because `line-height` is inherited.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  margin:0.5em 0 0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA &amp; AAAAA</span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em">BBBBB · BBBBB · BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:0.5em"><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCCCCC &amp; CCCCCCCCCC</span></span></p>
</div>
```

Or define the `font-size` you are using for span inside `p`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.wrapper p {
  margin:0.5em 0 0;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:0.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p style="text-align:center"><span ><span style="color:#00bcd4;">AAAAA &amp; AAAAA</span></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span >BBBBB · BBBBB · BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB</span></p>
  <p style="text-align:center"><span><span style="color:#00bcd4;">CCCCCCCC &amp; CCCCCCCCCC</span></span></p>
</div>
```

---

Related 
questions for more detail and examples: [Line height issue with inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54341767/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have added `display: inline-block` in `<span>. span and paragraphs are supposed to be`display: inline`.

Remove

```
.wrapper p span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and add

```
.wrapper p span {
  display: inline;
}
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Ahh, but that adds a lot of space between lines when wrapped. So it doesn’t really fix the issue.

Comment: paragraphs are **block-level** elements not `inline`.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am talking about span used inside p