# Why does vertical-align: text-top make element go down?

Tags: html, css

I'm puzzled about working vertical-align property. How does it work? If you explain me how it works I'll be thankful:)
Why does that property work differently? In the first case I try to align my text by vertical-align: text-top, but... my text goes down. Why?
In the second case I align my square by vertical-align: text-top and this property works properly. What's the difference? Why my text goes down instead of rising?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  line-height: 50px;
}


.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three">yellow</span> background <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: text-top;` _Aligns the top of the element with the top of the parent element's font._

Comment: @RobMoll and? what is the top of the element and what is the top of the parent element's font?

Comment: @RobMoll yes, it does. But it still doesn't explain the difference in behavior in these two cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height</sup>

To understand this you need to first consider the definition of `text-top`:

> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline element, or to the strut of a parent block container element.
>
> In the following definitions, for inline non-replaced elements, the box used for alignment is the box **whose height is the 'line-height'** (containing the box's glyphs and the half-leading on each side, see above).

Then

> text-top
>
> Align the **top of the box** with the **top of the parent's content area**

So we need to identify the *top of the box* and the *top of the parent's content area*

If we add some decorations, we can easily identify them

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 7px/100% 2px no-repeat
   yellow;
}

p span {
  background:green;
}

.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background:red;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three">yellow</span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

The green coloration define the content area and we can clearly see that the square is aligned with that top. Until now it's trivial.

The tricky case is the text because we see that the red doesn't align with the green. This is due to the `line-height`. In the above it's said that we consider the box whose height is the `line-height` and we know that `line-height` is inherited so our span (the red one) will inherit the 50px line-height and this is our reference for the alignment.

Which is more tricky is that even if we change the line-height, the content area doesn't change (the red coloration will always stay the same)

> The 'height' property does not apply. **The height of the content area should be based on the font**

and

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. **But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box.**

To make it easy, imagine the text inside an invisible box with a height equal to `50px` and this box is aligned at the top of the parent content area then inside that box you have your text and the background coloration will only cover the content area whataver the line-height.

If you use a `line-height` equal to the content area you will have a *perfect* alignment:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 7px/100% 2px no-repeat
   yellow;
}

p span {
  background:green;
}

.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background:red;
  line-height:33px;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three">yellow</span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

Increase the `line-height` and you will have a bigger *invisible* box and the text will move more down:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 7px/100% 2px no-repeat
   yellow;
}

p span {
  background:green;
}

.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background:red;
  line-height:100px;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three">yellow</span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

And logically with a small line-height, it will go up:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 7px/100% 2px no-repeat
   yellow;
}

p span {
  background:green;
}

.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background:red;
  line-height:1px;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three">yellow</span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

---

If you change the display to `inline-block` you will better see the issue because the coloration will cover the whole area defined by `line-height`

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 7px/100% 2px no-repeat
   yellow;
}

p span {
  background:green;
}

.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three">yellow</span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

And with more element we can better illustrate our invisible box:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 50px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 7px/100% 2px no-repeat
   yellow;
}

p span {
  background:green;
}

.three {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  outline:1px solid blue;
  background:transparent;
  display:inline-block;
}
.three > span {
  background:red;
}
  

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three"><span>yellow</span></span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three" style="line-height:100px"><span>yellow</span></span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>


<div>
  <p><span class="one">I'm</span> <span class="two">on the</span> <span class="three" style="line-height:1px"><span>yellow</span></span> <span>background</span> <span class="block"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: how did you calculate the `line-height:33px;`?

Comment: the height of the span which is the height of the content area

Comment: ok thanks I understand now https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjo4d.png

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! It's the best explanation I've ever seen

Comment: @Eva in case you are intrested here is some other related questions to get more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978130/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/54341767/8620333