# What is the rule or rules that apply in the alignment of the element that has vertical-align property?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to understand what are the rules that are applyed to the elements that have the `vertical-align` css property by which the elements takes the referents for their alignment.
I have been trying all combinations I could imagine, to understand what is the reference that each element take to align itself. In some articles, in almost all I have read, say that the reference is the parent, but as far as I been trying combinations, that is not accurate.
What I did to find the rules by which the elements take de reference for the alignment :

- try all combination:

  - elements with this property
  - elements wihtout this property
  - changing size
  - changing the order of elements in the container

After exhausting all combinations, I can't reach a rule/rules by which the elements get they reference for their alignment,

- because:

  - that change depending which element is bigger
  - that change depending of the order of elements
  - that change if some have and other don't this property

So, By myself I can't reach a conclusion of the rules. I have observe that that reference changes depending of the situation.
My question is:
What are the rules that the element takes in order to chose the reference for its alignment.

I post the code for the context I have used to study this topic. I don't think posting all combinations code will be usefull for helping understand what is my question about.

HTMLS:

```
   <div class="P">
       <div class="block-1" style="vertical-align: bottom;"> 1 </div>
       <div class="block-2" style="vertical-align: middle;"> 2 </div>
       <div class="block-3" style=""> 3 </div> 
       <div class="block-4" style="vertical-align: middle;"> 4 </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .P { height:400px; width:80%; border:5px rgb(224, 167, 11) solid; }
        .block-1 { height:250px; width:75px; border:5px rgb(234, 238, 13) solid }
        .block-2 { height:65px; width:30%; border:5px rgb(48, 175, 16) solid }
        .block-3 { height:275px; width:50px; border:5px rgb(43, 126, 17) solid }
        .block-4 { height:25px;width:18px;border:black 5px solid; }
        .P div   { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: basically 2 rules (1) either the baseline or (2) the top/bottom of the linebox: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height

Comment: some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190413/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635716/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319772/8620333